Load multiple images from Photos folder causes Out of Memory Exception
I have a small application that wraps a website that processes pictures. I can not upload more than 5 pictures from my phone, the application crashes with error:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a xxxxx byte allocation.
How do I optimize memory management? I would greatly appreciate any advice.
User Selects images
 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        val selectedImageBlobs = mutableListOf<Triple<String, String, String>>()

        if (data?.clipData != null) {
            val clipData = data.clipData
            for (i in 0 until clipData!!.itemCount) {
                val uri = clipData.getItemAt(i).uri
                val base64Image = convertUriToBase64(uri)
                val mimeType = contentResolver.getType(uri)
                val fileName = getFileNameWithExtension(uri)
                if (base64Image != null && mimeType != null && fileName.isNotEmpty()) {
                    selectedImageBlobs.add(Triple(base64Image, mimeType, fileName))
                }
            }
        } else {
            val uri = data?.data
            if (uri != null) {
                val base64Image = convertUriToBase64(uri)
                val mimeType = contentResolver.getType(uri)
                val fileName = getFileNameWithExtension(uri)
                if (base64Image != null && mimeType != null && fileName.isNotEmpty()) {
                    selectedImageBlobs.add(Triple(base64Image, mimeType, fileName))
                }
            }
        }

        // Send selected image blobs, MIME types, and filenames to JSBridge
        jsBridge.sendImagePaths(selectedImageBlobs)
    }
}

This function is where the image data is read from the device's storage, converted to a Base64 string, and returned(consuming a significant amount of memory


 private fun convertUriToBase64(uri: Uri): String? {
        return try {
            val inputStream: InputStream? = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
            val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
            var bytesRead: Int

            while (inputStream!!.read(buffer).also { bytesRead = it } != -1) {
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
            }

            val byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()
            Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            null
        }
    }

And then I send data:

    private inner class JSBridge(val context: Context, private val webView: WebView) {
        fun sendData(imageFiles: List<Triple<String, String, String>>) {
            val jsonArray = JSONArray()

            for (imageFile in imageFiles) {
                val jsonObject = JSONObject()
                jsonObject.put("type", imageFile.second)
                jsonObject.put("name", imageFile.third)
                jsonObject.put("blob", imageFile.first)
                jsonArray.put(jsonObject)
            }

            val jsonData = """
                {
                    "method": "upload_files_from_app",
                    "result": {
                        "imageFiles": $jsonArray
                    }
                }
            """.trimIndent()

            val jsonObject = JSONObject(jsonData)
            val jsonObjectString = jsonObject.toString()
            Log.d("WebViewBridge", "JSBridge JSON Object: $jsonObjectString")

            // Call JavaScript function with JSON data
            webView.evaluateJavascript("javascript: window.mobile2web.onMessage($jsonObjectString)", null)
        }


On Create:


   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Request location permissions if not already granted
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE
            )
        }

        val settings: WebSettings = myWebView.settings
        settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        settings.domStorageEnabled = true

        myWebView.webViewClient = MyWebViewClient()
        myWebView.webChromeClient = MyWebChromeClient()
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://********************")

        val jsInterface = JSBridge(this, myWebView)
        myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "androidBridge")
    }



Why don't you downscale the image in function onActivityResult after line clipData.getItemAt(i).uri . If you think that gone help you and fulfils the requirement then I can post it as answer below.

Converting images to a base64 string is not efficient and will take up a large amount of memory due to the entire image is put into memory.
Depending on the size of the images you will only be able to send a few images at a time.
its not exactly clear what you do with these images when you try to send it to the webview but if you are trying to upload them to a server you should not upload them via a base64 string

Thanks for your response.  Webview will print the images. Images need to be intact, I can't reduce their size. What would be an  efficient way to upload the images?

If you are passing the images to the webview to display there really is no other way than to do base64 but IMO you need to rethink the whole process you are doing here. without knowing what exactly is happening I cant really help other than to say substitute the webview with native android imageviews to display the images

The website is doing all the work unfortunatelly, webview is just a wrapper. The requirement is to do minimum development natively and do everithing on the web. When a user selects the images, the website creates an order, and allows us to print and ship the images. We don't need to display them in the app, but we need to injest them into the website.
So  maybe I somehow can slow down the process and process the images one by one  while monitoring memory usage? I am also adding onCreate method that makes almost entire application.

The problem that you have to decide how you want to fix is that because of the requirement that you dont want to do anything native you have then severely limited yourself in options since you need to send the image via a string to the webview. You need to reevaluate this decision or come up with some other way to send the images to a website like sending the images to a backend server first then have the website show the images.
